Using @PlanningScore and @PlanningEntityProperty
I am using some code generated by GTPChat.
One of the files generated is called EnergyScheduleSolution.java and it has two associated imports:
import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningEntityProperty;
import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningScore;

And associated annotations: @PlanningScore and @PlanningEntityProperty
I get the following errors in my Eclipse IDE:

The import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningEntityProperty cannot be resolved
The import ai.timefold.solver.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningScore cannot be resolved
PlanningEntityProperty cannot be resolved to a type
PlanningScore cannot be resolved to a type

What am I missing?
I have googled around for the imports to no avail. I think the two pairs of errors are related. But I cannot find anything that matches the problem.

You wrote (in your question): What am I missing? Probably the relevatn Timefold libraries.

If you are using Maven, you would need to add the following to the dependencies section of pom.xml:
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ai.timefold.solver</groupId>
      <artifactId>timefold-solver-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ai.timefold.solver</groupId>
    <artifactId>timefold-solver-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

If you are using gradle, you need to add the following to the dependencies section of build.gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation platform("ai.timefold.solver:timefold-solver-bom:1.12.0")
    implementation "ai.timefold.solver:timefold-solver-core"
}

Regardless of which build tool you use, you also need to make sure Eclipse is setup to recognize your Maven/Gradle project; see these StackOverflow questions for details on how to do that:

How to build and run Maven projects after importing into Eclipse IDE (Maven)
Create Eclipse Java Gradle Project (Gradle)

For a "Hello World" guide on using Timefold, see https://docs.timefold.ai/timefold-solver/latest/quickstart/hello-world/hello-world-quickstart or the hello-world quickstart (https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/java/hello-world).
